# Cannot boot Windows 10 after installing Lubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

Before it, I install Debian 11 dual-boot and everything worked, Windows can boot, no problem. Then after some time I installed Lubuntu 22.04 LTS over Debian, but after it I cannot boot to my Windows 10. I even go to BIOS->Boot and not see anything like Windows. Also on Lubuntu's grub I didn't see Windows.

So I use the boot-repair on live USB, and press the `recommended option`. It says something like `legacy Widndows detected`. And it reinstalls the grub. I believe that Windows bootloader are on `/dev/sda1` because when I use Debian I can see that on Debian grub that say: `Windows boot manager on /dev/sda1/`. After boot-repair I see 2 more option on Lubuntu grub: `Windows on /dev/sda3` and `Windows on /dev/sda4/`, nothing like `Windows on /dev/sda1/`. I press Enter...And error, Windows can't boot.

Then I boot to Linux and do:

```
# sudo fdisk -l
lot of text...
Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34     262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  1794152448 1801965567   7813120   3,7G Linux swap
/dev/sda3      468992    1492991   1024000   500M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4     1492992  410324637 408831646 194,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   410324992  411375615   1050624   513M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   411377664 1195761663 784384000   374G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1195761664 1794152447 598390784 285,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8      262178     468991    206814   101M BIOS boot
/dev/sda9  1801965568 1953523711 151558144  72,3G Linux filesystem
```

So I think Windows is not removed, I just can't access it.

My laptop is Asus X302U.

Also, this is the [pastebin from boot repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DN9vG2DnC3/).

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think you’ve got an old bios windows installation and Ubuntu is uefi. In your Bios settings, if there’s a ‘legacy’ option you might find you can then boot widows (but not Lubuntu). You need both to be either bios (legacy) or both uefi, not one of each.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, I have already think about that. Maybe I will try to reinstall Lubuntu.

Comment: You show a gpt partitioned drive. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt drives. But it looks like you overwrote the ESP - efi system partition with swap? You show Microsoft reserved as sda1 which Windows requires on gpt drives before first NTFS partition. You need an ESP to repair and boot Windows and then better to have Lubuntu in UEFI boot mode. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)